# Is there any function such as repmat for struct in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook, julia-studio

would you please help me. I want to produce a population of struct in Julia.In matalab,we can use repmat for a structure. but in Julia it is impossible. is there any function like repmat in Julia?

for example:

```
npop=20;
struct individual
    position
    cost
end

individual1=individual([],[])

repmat(individual1,npop,1)
repeat(individual1,npop,1)
```

```
repmat(individual1,npop,1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching repmat(::individual, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  repmat(::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T, ::Int64, ::Int64) at abstractarray
math.jl:311
  repmat(::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T, ::Integer, ::Integer) at abstracta
rraymath.jl:334
  repmat(::AbstractArray{T,1} where T, ::Int64) at abstractarraymath.jl:325
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JuliaPro-0.6.4.1\pkgs-0.6.4.1\v0.6\Atom\src\rep
l.jl:118 [inlined]
 [2] anonymous at .\<missing>:?

julia>

julia> repmat(individual1,npop,1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching repmat(::individual, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  repmat(::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T, ::Int64, ::Int64) at abstractarray
math.jl:311
  repmat(::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T, ::Integer, ::Integer) at abstracta
rraymath.jl:334
  repmat(::AbstractArray{T,1} where T, ::Int64) at abstractarraymath.jl:325
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JuliaPro-0.6.4.1\pkgs-0.6.4.1\v0.6\Atom\src\rep
l.jl:118 [inlined]
 [2] anonymous at .\<missing>:?
```

if loop is used it is possible

```
pop=individual([],[])
for i=2:npop

    pop=[pop;individual1]

end
```

and

```
julia> pop
20-element Array{individual,1}:
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
 individual(Any[], Any[])
```

but I couldn't find a function like repmat in Julia.

Comment: Are you looking for [`repeat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.repeat)?

Comment: it is also dosent work for struct

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question by adding what you have as input and what the expected result is.

Comment: Have you considered using an `Array{Individual,1}` that'll represent your population?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve correctly (assuming you want to do a kind of ABM) this is the way to do it:

```
[individual([],[]) for i in 1:npop]
```

In this way every individual will be allocated separately (and this is probably what you want).

As a side note it would be better to add types to `position` and `cost` for performance reasons. Here is an example assuming that `position` will be a vector of two element tuples containing a position and `cost` is a vector of floats:

```
struct individual
    position::Vector{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}
    cost::Vector{Float64}
end
```

And then you should write:

```
[individual(Tuple{Float64,Float64}[],Float64[]) for i in 1:npop]
```

**EDIT**

Note that `struct` in Julia is not mutable. This means that you cannot rebind the values that `position` and `cost` point to. Therefore you have two options.

#### Option 1. Define a struct as mutable like this:

```
mutable struct individual
    position
    cost
end
```

and then the code you have written will work.

#### Option 2 Update without rebinding

update a vector in a struct that is not mutable without rebinding it. E.g. (using your original definitions)

```
pop = [individual([],[]) for i in 1:npop]
for i=1:npop
    append!(pop[i].position, rand(0:1,10))
end
```

or simply initialize it as needed:

```
pop = [individual(rand(0:1,10),[]) for i in 1:npop]
```

As an additional comment please note that in Julia you generally do not need to make an adjoint as you did in `(rand(0:1,10))'`. Operating on vectors typically good enough. And in Option 2 (normal `struct` you would not be able to append 2-dimensional object to `[]` which is 1-dimensional).

Comment: . would you please help me again. how can I initialize `individual`.
`for i=1:npop

    pop[i].position=(rand(0:1,10))'
end`
why has it  Error?

Thank you

Comment: I will expand the answer to cover this case.

Comment: if you don't mind can I ask another help?
I want to have a population with 2 columns. I coded like this `popc = [individual(rand(0:1,nvar),[]) for i in 1:4,j in 1:2]`. is there any thing that I don't have to use j?
thanks very much

Comment: I personally like this double indexing as it is explicit about what is going on. You can alternatively write e.g. `reshape([individual(rand(0:1,nvar),[]) for i in 1:npop], :, 2)` or `map(x -> individual(rand(0:1,nvar),[]), zeros(4, 2))` but I think that none of them are simpler.